# Django referrer question

Tags: python, regex, django, referrer

I want to know who refers my webpage, so in my models I have:

```
referrer = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='google',
        verbose_name=_('referrer'), help_text=_('Referrer'))
```

This are the URL's for my page:

```
url(r'^$', app_views.index, name='index_default')
```

and

```
url(r'^(\w+)/$', app_views.index, name='index_default2')
```

I want to send my referrer parameter to the flash embeddeded within my HTML along flashvars:

```
< param name="FlashVars" value="referrer={{ referrer }}" />
```

How should the view look like in order to catch the referrer matched with the regular expression? Something like

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',
            {
            'referrer':referrer,
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327078/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-django)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the meta dictionary of request there is a HTTP_REFERER value .. I think that can help you

Comment: thank you. so can it work something like that?`def index(request, referrer=request.META['HTTP_REFERER']):
 return render_to_response('index.html',
   {
   'referrer':referrer,
   },
   context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: def index(request):
 referrer=request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
 return render_to_response('index.html', { 'referrer':referrer, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))