# How to get the previous URL in Django

Tags: django

I'll give the step by step info.

Let's say we're in the about page, the URL is `example.com/about`.
There's an email a friend button, when clicked, the URL is `example.com/emailafriend`.
Then when I clicked the submit button, the referal URL will be submitted is `example.com/emailafriend`. Question, how to get the about page URL? BTW, I'm using `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could work with the [request path attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) and add that to your form's action attribute, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="/tell-a-friend?return_url={{ request.path }}">
...
</form>
```

Then, in your tell-a-friend view, [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to the `return_url` query parameter.

Comment: That's definitely a good approach that will stick with redirects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe you are using [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) which will do a redirect if you don't have a slash. Try changing the button link to `sample.com/emailafriend/`, note the ending slash.

Comment: according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: I already using that request. But when you clicked the submit button, the referal page is already sample.com/emailafriend, not about anymore.

Comment: in my sample, there's already a slash Matt. Forgot to type it. sorry. So, right now, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply pass sample.com/about as GET or POST param? Or even through session.