# How to get the previous URL from a POST in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, url

I have a Post model that requires a certain category before being added to the database, and I want the category to be generated automatically. Clicking the addPost button takes you to a different page and so the category will be determined by taking a part of the previous page URL.

Is there a way to get the previous page URL as a string?

I have added my AddPost button here.

```html
<aside class="addPost">
    <article>
        <form action="/Forum/addPost">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Post"/>
        </form>
    </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327078/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-django)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do that by using `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it will exist if only your tab previous page was from your website, else there will be no `HTTP_REFERER` in META `dict`. So be careful and make sure that you are using `.get()` notation instead.

```
# Returns None if user came from another website
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

*Note: I gave this answer when Django 1.10 was an actual release. I'm not working with Django anymore, so I can't tell if this applies to Django 2*

Comment: name 'self' is not defined?

Comment: just simply add self.request if you use class based view

Comment: It also applies to Django 5.0 (and previous versions):
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

Answer (score 9):

You can get the referring URL by using `request.META.HTTP_REFERER`

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: Apologies, I don't quite follow how that works. Could you explain? If I was able to retrieve the URL this way would it allow me to treat it as type string?

Comment: when trying to use request.META.HTTP_REFERER I get an error saying dict object has no attribute HTTP_REFERER.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer @tryingtolearn comment, but for future people, you can use `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: This could raise a `KeyError` causing the page to crash; using `dict.get()` as described in the accepted answer would prevent this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding it to your context, then passing it to the template, you can place it in your template directly with:

```html
    <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">Return</a>
```

Comment: This is raising MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: @justbeingalearner sounds like your reverse proxy is not adding the header

Answer (score 2):

A much more reliable method would be to explicitly pass the category in the URL of the Add Post button.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate? I'm a definite newbie to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get **the previous url** in **"views.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
    
    pre_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') # Here
        
    return render(request, 'test/index.html')
```

You can also get **the previous url** in **Django Template** as shown below:

```html
# "index.html"

{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}
```