# Make view accessible only through redirect and from only one view in Django

Tags: python, django

How do I make a view to be only accessible through *redirect* and from a only a particular *view*?

**urls.py**:

```
#Assuming namespace = 'myApp'

url(r'^redarekt/$', views.redarekt, name='redarekt'),
url(r'^reciva/$', views.reciva, name='reciva'),
```

**views.py**:

```
@login_required()
def redarekt(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_active:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myApp:reciva'))


@login_required()
def reciva(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_active:
        #CHECK IF IT IS A REDIRECT AND COMING FROM redarekt
            execute(request)
        raise Http404
    raise Http404
```

How do I make `reciva` to be only accessible through *redirect* and from a only `redarekt`?

Comment: I am not posting this as an answer, as I am not sure it will fill your need, but check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325505/django-getting-previous-url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`request.session`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)

```
@login_required()
def redarekt(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_active:
        request.session['pp_redarekt'] = True
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myApp:reciva'))


@login_required()
def reciva(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_active:
        if 'pp_redarekt' in request.session:
            execute(request)
            del request.session['pp_redarekt']
        raise Http404
    raise Http404
```

`'pp_redarekt'` stands for Previous Page 'redarekt'

So basically, before redirecting to `reciva(request)` view you're setting adding session key, that says that previous page was `redarekt`. When you handle your request in `reciva` view, you are deleting that key, so user won't be able to enter `reciva` twice or more.

But for doing so, you need to setup your sessions. [Guide and docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: A brilliant solution. Thank you.

Comment: For Djanog newbies - `execute(request)` isn't actually part of the code!  I spent 15 minutes trying to find where to import `execute` from, but it is just OP showing that you are supposed to write your own code here.

Comment: @Valachio sure it's specific to OP's question. Maybe OP has `execute()` function, it should not be important.