# Getting Previous URL in Django Form

Tags: python, django

So i'm trying to build something, so that users would be able to report something on site. Here's the model,

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reporting_url = models.URLField()
    message = models.TextField()
```

Here's the view,

```
def report(request):
url_report = ???
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReportForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        new_form.reporting_url = url_report
        new_form.save()
```

I can't use something like,

```
url_report = request.get_full_path()
```

since I need to create/edit several views & repeat things in that case.

When I'm using something like,

```
url_report = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

it's returning the URL of same page from where the from is written. I'm using something like,

```
<a href="{% url 'contact:report' %}">Report</a>
```

to reach the Report form from several different apps/html_pages.
How can I get the URL of previous page from where user has pressed the "Report" button?

Please help me with this code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: getting previous url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325505/django-getting-previous-url)

Comment: @gitblame This is not a duplicate of said question. The OP knows how to get the previous URL, just not how to persist it beyond the current request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the referer in the session whenever the `Report` button is pressed:

```
def report(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        request.session['report_url'] = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.reporting_url = request.session.get('report_url')
            new_form.save()
```

You have to persist this referer beyond one request-response cycle. The session is the designated way to do that. Another option would be to render that url as a hidden form field, but that can be easily tampered with.

Comment: Wow, Working Perfectly fine. Thank You very much Sir :)

Comment: This can be easily broken by having two windows open at the same time and doing separate posts. The session acts a stateful singleton but forms are stateless. It's better to store the url in a hidden form field and retrieve it from there, since each form will carry its own URL, regardless of the session state.

Comment: No doubt: if a user wants to cheat, this is not airtight. But you cannot guarantee that either way. The HTTP referer header is just as easily forged as post data. Given normal usage this at least gives you the referer url of the last GET on your report page.

Comment: @Soviut Sir, Can you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Sir, I couldn't get it why it's not Safe to use directly. Can you plz explain a little ?

Comment: @DodvalShivam Unsave is a strong word. You should just know that any of the two options has its caveats. Hiding a form field does not prevent a user form posting fake data, and you can also manually fake the REFERER HTTP header. But after all, you can never know for sure what a user has been doing before they post to your page. Assuming the user has no bad intents, my answer gives you the page he visited before the last time he performed a GET on this view (in any tab), the hidden form field will give you the  last page he visited before the GET that actually served the form that he posted.