# How to determine previous URL in django

Tags: python, django

How do I find the previous URL that referred to the current one in Django?

For example, I want different output from my home page if it was referred from the login page or from the sign up page or from elsewhere?

I can see what I want in the Referer section of Request Headers in Chrome Developer Tools, but I can't seem to access the value using `request.referer`.

I don't want to append the referer using `index.html?return_url={{ request.path }}` because I'm not certain where it's coming from.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: getting previous url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325505/django-getting-previous-url)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327078/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-django)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `self.request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`, more useful meta headers in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

```
previous_url = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```