# how to get previous page url in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

## I don't have the views.py using PasswordResetViews!

## i am using the django password reset but i want my template to behave differently when it come from password_rest_email and from password_reset_confirm

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
#from django.urls import path
from dappx import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView,PasswordResetDoneView,PasswordResetCompleteView,PasswordResetConfirmView
# SET THE NAMESPACE!
app_name = 'dappx'
# Be careful setting the name to just /login use userlogin instead!
urlpatterns=[
    url('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    url('user_login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url('google_login/', views.google_login, name='google_login'),
    url('special/', views.special, name='special'),
    url('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('password_reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    url('password_reset/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),

]
```

i need that template i.e(password_reset_confirm) to show email is send when it come from password_reset_email and show password reset successful if it come from password_reset_confirm

password_reset_complete.html

```
{% extends 'dappx/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Check your Email{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-6  col-md-4">
        <div class="jumbotron">
<h4>The password reset link has been sent to youre Email</h4>
<br>
<p>Check your email to reset the password. You can log in now on the <a href="{% url 'dappx:user_login' %}">log in page</a>.</p>
<br>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the previous URL in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327078/how-to-get-the-previous-url-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not comment posts yet, so I just write this as an answer. The following link provides a tutorial about the django built in authentication. There is logic for a view that tells the user that an email has been sent 'Password Reset Done View' and logic for a view that tells if it was successfull 'Password Reset Complete View'.

[Django Tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html#password-reset)

Answer (score 2):

Seems duplicate of [Django: getting previous url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325505/django-getting-previous-url)

You can always pass GET variable with information you want and in subsequent view, it can be used directly.

Comment: i don't have the views.py  it need to be done in template?

Comment: You can use {{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }} directly in the template and compare against it.